# Is there a way to return the number of columns in a table?

Tags: templating

Is there a way to return the number of columns in a table?

I tried {{ entry.tableHandle | length }} but this seems to return the number of rows rather than columns.

I've got a site with a couple of tables and I'm trying to output the number of columns in a given table to use for my CSS responsive column width.

I.E. If table was 2 columns, it would output a 2 and I would use that to set column width to 50% etc...

Answer (score 1):

`entry.tableHandle` is an array of all of the rows, and each row is an array with keys that are the column names and values that are the column values **AND** keys that are `col1`, `col2`, etc. and values that are the column values.

So you can do `entry.tableHandle[0]|keys` to get the keys, `entry.tableHandle[0]|keys|length` to get the number of keys, and finally `(entry.tableHandle[0]|keys|length)/2` to get the number of columns.

You will want to check first that there is a row in the table - this won't work if there is no row `0`.